# SSIS XML date conversion error

Tags: xml, date, ssis

I have an XMl document with this date format: 2012-11-12T00:00:00-05:00

When setting this column to DateType 'Date[DT_DATE]' (or DataBase Date or DataBase Time) in the Data Conversion task - the task fails with the common error: 
"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

So I know I need to use the 'Derived Column' task to cast this value first...

...But what do I cast it to?

My destination field in the DB table is DATETIME type.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had to substring the format and it works...
A bit of nuisance.